# CouchDB multiple constraints

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb

I have a set of documents in CouchDB that are geolocalized - that is, they have a structure like

```
{
  _id: ...,
  ...
  coords: {
    lat: 45.204149214,
    long: 40.284712972
  }
}
```

I want to be able to display them on a map. This requires me to get all documents in a given square. It is easy to get all documents with longitude in a given interval:

```
// map function
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.coords.long, doc.other_stuff);
}
```

using a query like

```
// query
/path/to/view/?startkey=40&endkey=50
```

The problem is that I do not see how to do multidimensional constraints. How to get all documents with latitude between, say, 20 **and** 30 and longitude between 40 and 50? I see I can specify multiple keys, but that will **or** the results.

One option would be to do further filtering on the client, but given the size of the data, this may be unfeasible.

**Disclaimer**: there are a few [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036828/does-couchdb-support-multiple-range-queries) questions on SO, basically stating that this is not possible. Since they all look dated, I would like to know whether something has changed in the latest releases of CouchDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot do multidimensional queries. But there is [GeoCouch](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch). It pretty easy to add to couch db through [build-couchdb](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb#couchdb-plugins), or you can use iriscouch hosting which has it baked in by default.

As you can see [Using Geocouch](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch#using-geocouch) is fairly easy, and a query takes a bounding box like this :

`http://localhost:5984/places/_design/main/_spatial/points?bbox=0,0,180,90`

If you dont want to use geocouch (for some reason), I have successfully used a [GeoHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) which maps the two dimensions into a one dimensional space.  [Here](https://github.com/ryanramage/eckoit/blob/master/app.js#L187) is the view code, and [here](https://github.com/ryanramage/eckoit/blob/master/html/js/app.js#L361) is the query. As you can see, it is not as elegant, but it is portable across couchdb versions, and it also works.